# Add Text to an MySQL-Exception

Tags: c#, exception, mysql-connector

i would like to add text to an Exception but the Problem is, that i've wrote my own return type and i want to add it to the method, which is returning exceptions, so that i can really add my text to ALL Excpetion.

The problem is, that i'm currently working on a database application and there are just to much Exceptions and i don't want to add those string/s for each exception.

I'm working with the MySQL-Connector for .NET and i want to add an small information to some numbers, like mysqlex.Number 1042 and some others, but how can i do that?

Is there any way to add something to those Exception or say something like mysql-exception + additionaltext?

Comment: Why not create a new exception with the original as the inner exception? Failing that, you'll need to show us roughly what you're doing as your description isn't very clear. Code would be ideal

Comment: Because i'm already in the Return class. 

I would have to override my Exception var then, because i can't add another var to the Methode then. (Is that possible?)

If i have sonething like this:
Public MyReturnType(MySqlException mysqlex, ...)
{
    Here i want to modify the Exception
}

Comment: To clarify, you've got a method that _returns_ a specific type of exception rather than throwing an exception? I'm not familiar with the mysql connector but this seems like an anti-pattern, unless it's a helper method specifically designed to generate exceptions to be thrown immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you create an exception class that derives from a MySQLException.

```
public class ProtonMySQLException : MySQLException
{
    public int protonNumber = 0;
    public string protonSpecialText = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: This solution may have worked in 2014, but in 2020, MySqlException is sealed (meaning it can't be inherited.) :(